# How can I curl about:cache in firefox?

Tags: firefox, html, curl, browser-cache

In firefox, I can go to about:cache and display all entries that are written to disk.
I need the HTML source code of that page, but from terminal.

I am thinking of something like:

```
curl about:cache?storage=disk&context=
```

but that obviously does not work, because curl can't resolve the host.
Is there another way to get the source of that page, without clicking through firefox? I can open it on terminal in a new firefox instance with

```
firefox view-source:about:cache?storage=disk&context=
```

but I don't know how to "download" it.

Thanks!

Comment: try https://github.com/abiyani/automate-save-page-as

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get that info from the command line, the page is generated internally by Firefox.

The best you can do is load it in Firefox and the right-click then save-as

Comment: You're right that curl cannot do it. But I can imagine that tools such as http://www.seleniumhq.org can get it done.